# Command to execute script at specific time

Tags: r, windows, date, rstudio

How do I make a command to auto execute a script in Rstudio? I have a script in Rstudio to handle a database, but I need it to be run at 7:00 AM, automatically.
My operation system is Windows and i can't install the cronR. Exist other mode??

Comment: Why install cron when Windows already has scheduled tasks? Search for `Task Scheduler`

Answer (score 1):

Try package [cronR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/README.html):

"*Schedule R scripts/processes with the cron scheduler. This allows R users working on Unix/Linux to automate R processes on specific timepoints from R itself. Mark that if you are looking for a Windows scheduler, you might be interested in the R package taskscheduleR available at https://github.com/bnosac/taskscheduleR.
The package contains also an RStudio add-in.*"